# Realm Android information about Change

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, realm

is there something like RealmCollectionChange class from java in realm?

If not, how to get information about the changes in a table or query?

That problem is that the cause `notifyDataSetChange()` or `notifyItemRangeChanged(0, size())` bad for recyclerView.

More information:

**In RealmRecyclerAdapter:**

```
public RealmRecyclerViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<T> data, boolean autoUpdate) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context can not be null");
        }

        this.context = context;
        this.adapterData = data;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.hasAutoUpdates = autoUpdate;

        // Right now don't use generics, since we need maintain two different
        // types of listeners until RealmList is properly supported.
        // See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/989
        this.listener = hasAutoUpdates ? new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(Object results) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } : null;
    }
```

**And 
I wrote to the adapter, which partially solves the problem, but not completely:**

```
  public abstract class RealmAD<T extends RealmModel, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    private static final List<Long> EMPTY_LIST = new ArrayList(0);

    protected List ids;
    @Nullable
    private RealmResults<T> adapterData;

    private RealmFieldType animatePrimaryIdType;
    private long animatePrimaryColumnIndex;


    public RealmAD(RealmResults<T> adapterData) {
        this.adapterData = adapterData;
        this.adapterData.addChangeListener(getRealmChangeListener());
        this.animatePrimaryColumnIndex = adapterData.getTable().getTable().getPrimaryKey();
        this.animatePrimaryIdType = adapterData.getTable().getColumnType(this.animatePrimaryColumnIndex);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return isDataValid() ? adapterData.size() : 0;
    }

    @Nullable
    public T getItem(int index) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        return isDataValid() ? adapterData.get(index) : null;
    }

    private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> getRealmChangeListener() {
        return element -> {
            if (RealmAD.this.ids != null && !RealmAD.this.ids.isEmpty()) {
                List newIds = RealmAD.this.getIdsOfRealmResults();
                if (newIds.isEmpty()) {
                    RealmAD.this.ids = newIds;
                    RealmAD.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return;
                }

                Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(RealmAD.this.ids, newIds);
                List deltas = patch.getDeltas();
                RealmAD.this.ids = newIds;
                if (!deltas.isEmpty()) {
                    Iterator delta2 = deltas.iterator();

                    while (delta2.hasNext()) {
                        Delta delta3 = (Delta) delta2.next();
                        if (delta3.getType() == Delta.TYPE.INSERT) {
                            RealmAD.this.notifyItemRangeInserted(delta3.getRevised().getPosition(), delta3.getRevised().size());
                        } else if (delta3.getType() == Delta.TYPE.DELETE) {
                            RealmAD.this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(delta3.getOriginal().getPosition(), delta3.getOriginal().size());
                        } else {
                            RealmAD.this.notifyItemRangeChanged(delta3.getRevised().getPosition(), delta3.getRevised().size());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                RealmAD.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                RealmAD.this.ids = RealmAD.this.getIdsOfRealmResults();
            }

        };
    }

    private List getIdsOfRealmResults() {
        if(this.adapterData != null && this.adapterData.size() != 0) {
            ArrayList ids;
            int i;

                ids = new ArrayList(this.adapterData.size());

                for(i = 0; i < this.adapterData.size(); ++i) {
                    ids.add(this.getRealmRowId(i));
                }

                return ids;
        } else {
            return EMPTY_LIST;
        }
    }

    private Object getRealmRowId(int realmIndex) {
        RealmObjectProxy proxy = (RealmObjectProxy)this.adapterData.get(realmIndex);
        Row row = proxy.realmGet$proxyState().getRow$realm();
        Object rowPrimaryId;

        animatePrimaryColumnIndex = adapterData.getTable().getTable().getPrimaryKey();
        if(this.animatePrimaryIdType == RealmFieldType.INTEGER) {
            rowPrimaryId = row.getLong(this.animatePrimaryColumnIndex);
        } else {
            if(this.animatePrimaryIdType != RealmFieldType.STRING) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown animatedIdType");
            }

            rowPrimaryId = row.getString(this.animatePrimaryColumnIndex);
        }
        return rowPrimaryId;
    }

    public Object getLastItem(){
        if(getData()!=null && getData().size()!=0){
            return getData().last();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean isDataValid() {
        return adapterData != null && adapterData.isValid();
    }

    public OrderedRealmCollection<T> getData() {
        return adapterData;
    }

    public int getPositionById(String id){
        return ids.indexOf(id);
    }
```

Comment: Check out Realm Change Listener - https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath in method onChange() "realm" not have information about changes.

Comment: when changes happen call -             invalidateView();

Comment: Show some of your code

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath please see my and realm code in my question

Comment: What you are looking for is called fine-grained notifications. There is an issue tracking it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/989 Until then, a work-around could be using `copyFromRealm()` and the DiffUtils class introduced in app compact v24.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior thanks, i see this git branch, i thing, what peoples have solving problems